# xquery- how to assign a number(in sequence) when obtaining a number of records via single query using FLWOR expression

Tags: xquery, flwor

While trying to process and obtain data from an XML document, I want to obtain a number of records using a single FLWOR expression-- I am doing this by using the 'let' clause to obtain the data-- so I have a number of rows of data.

Eg.

```
<div id="main">
    <p> Text #1</p>
    <p> Text #2</p>
    <p> Text #3</p>
    <p> Text #4</p>
</div>
```

Now, I understand how to get the 4 'p' elements -- however I would like to also assign a sequence number to each line -- viz. I want to obtain the text this way--

```
 <data>Text #1</data><sequence> Sequence #1</sequence>
 <data>Text #2</data><sequence> Sequence #2</sequence>
 <data>Text #3</data><sequence> Sequence #3</sequence>
 <data>Text #4</data><sequence> Sequence #4</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is a more elegant way than doing it like this.... but it works:

```
let $t := <div id="main">
  <p>Text A</p>
  <p>Text B</p>
  <p>Text C</p>
  <p>Text D</p>
</div>
for $pos in $t/p/position()
let $p := $t/p[$pos]
return (
  <data>{ $p/text() }</data>,
  <sequence>Sequence { $pos }</sequence>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not completely sure what string value you would to have for the `<sequence/>` element, one solution could look as follows:

```
for $p in <div id="main">
  <p>Text #1</p>
  <p>Text #2</p>
  <p>Text #3</p>
  <p>Text #4</p>
</div>/p
return (
  <data>{ $p/text() }</data>,
  <sequence>Sequence { replace($p, 'Text ', '') }</sequence>
)
```

Comment: the text i mentioned- Text #1 and so on-- is only indicative-- the actual text will be totally different and will not itself contain the sequence number within it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `at` keyword in the *FLWOR* expression's [`for` clause](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-xquery-for-clause):

```
declare variable $div :=
  <div id="main">
      <p> Text #1</p>
      <p> Text #2</p>
      <p> Text #3</p>
      <p> Text #4</p>
  </div>;

for $p at $pos in $div/p
return (
  <data>{$p/text()}</data>,
  <sequence>Sequence #{$pos}</sequence>
)
```